# Setup a Twilio TwiML message using Content Editor Template

Tags: servlets, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am trying to send a Content Editor template with TwiML to a WhatsApp contact using WebHook in Servlets. Can anyone please suggest any tutorial that can help me to set up a TwiML message with Content Editor Message?

Comment: There's no TwiML support ATM. Instead of responding with TwiML, can you respond with 200 OK and an empty body? Then [use the Twilio SDKto send the Content Editor Template following this documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content-editor/send-templates-created-with-the-content-editor).